# Water level rise due to body in water

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-statics

I recently came across a comment that when we push a rubber ball into water filled  in a bucket, the water level rises because of the force applied by our hand (i.e. the more force we apply, the more water rises). But I do believe it's absurd, water rise occurs as a function of volume (of our hand).

If water level rose with force applied, that would mean that if I moved my fingers in water, giving force to the body, without changing the immersed hand volume, then a water rise would occur. Isn't that creation of water from water?.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, please avoid writing in capital letters in the future. It is considered impolite.

You are right that the water level rises by an amount corresponding to the emerged volume. If you push a floating ball under the water surface, the level rises until the ball is completely covered with water. Of course, you'd have to apply a force to push the ball down and it's also this work (=force $\times$ distance) that is going into gravitational potential energy when the water level rises. But if you push the ball down even further, the water level remains constant. That is, assuming you can apply the force without emerging any other body in the water (e.g. the ball could be attached to a very thin rod). If you use your hand, you are right that the water level will rise by the newly emerged volume of your hand (and arm,...).

Well, I guess there is one way to raise the water level without emerging more volume, though. If you put a mixer in the water, the work it does by displacing water rapidly will in part be converted to heat, raising the temperature of the water which will ultimately expand the water volume (if the water temperature is already above 4°C). The effect is minute but it's there.